# capturar informações dos sites

Tags: php, xml, libcurl

Como o Buscapé e outros sites conseguem pegar as informações dos sites? é através do curl ou um xml que os sites das lojas disponibilizam?

Comment: Apesar das respostas serem boas e darem uma ideia de como e feito tal processo, não tem como saber realmente como o processo é feito, apenas os desenvolvedores destas empresas poderiam informar. Acredito que seja por "feeds" em alguns casos, mas não tem como ter certeza.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Existe várias formas e técnicas que consegue pegar informações de outros sites, o nome dado a esta técnica é `'parse'`, muitos programadores aqui falam erroneamente 'parseamento de site', se os sites oferecer o `XML` ao buscapé, logo o trabalho dos engenheiros do site cairá bastante por `XML` já conter as `tags` formatada corretamente, tornando o trabalho mais rápido para o `PHP`, pois o `simplexml_load_file` é bem rápido e fácil de se usar.

Mas caso o site não ofereça tal arquivo, a solução pode ser o `Crawling` para obter os links, ou o `cURL` mesmo, o `cURL` só vai servir para passar e obter os dados HTML do servidor remoto, usando algo como `POST` ou `GET`, aí pra "pegar" estes dados, pode usar o `DOMDocument`, que é o que mais uso em conjunto com o `DomXpath` que é uma subfunção do próprio `DOM` que serve para analisar o `HTML`, mas também tem o `Simple HTML DOM Parser`.

Eis um exemplo que acabei de fazer pra te mostrar, capturando dados do G1:

```
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true) and libxml_clear_errors();
    $header = "X-Forwarded-For: {$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']}";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,   "http://g1.globo.com/bemestar/noticia/2011/03/medica-orienta-sobre-o-que-fazer-em-caso-de-dor-de-ouvido-e-como-evita-la.html");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://g1.globo.com");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array($header));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $html = curl_exec($ch);
    $DOM = new DOMDocument();
    $DOM->loadHTML($html);
    $xpath = new DomXpath($DOM);
    $titulo = $xpath->query('//input[@name="materia_titulo"]/@value')->item(0);
    $letra = $xpath->query('//div[@id="materia-letra"]')->item(0);
    echo "Titulo da matéria: ". $titulo->nodeValue . "<p>" . "Conteúdo da matéria: "   .$letra->nodeValue;
```

Comment: Achei muito bom, Mas da um certo trabalho pegar o valor das tags do html e salvar em um banco de dados com varias tags de vários sites.

Comment: Dá sim um certo trabalho! mas fazendo uma arquitetura bem bolada, o serviço fica excelente!

Comment: pow legal essa parada. Funciona com qualquer website se usar curl Cassiano José?

Answer (score 4):

Depende dos sites, não é algo genérico.

Podem ir buscar informações a:

- sitemaps
- feeds de informação (JSON por exemplo)
- APIs
- crawling pelas páginas e links dos sites
- outros mecanismos...

Answer (score 3):

Há varias alternativas para buscar conteudo de um site:

- Parseando o site: Vai literalmente baixar o HTML e poderá verificar os elementos DOM da página. Biblioteca PHP para este fim: [Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)
- Parseando o XML fornecido pelo site: Pode-se usar as funções nativas do PHP para isto, veja exemplo abaixo:

  ```
  $feed = simplexml_load_file($feedLink, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);

  foreach($feed->channel->item AS $item){
      if($count == $limit){
          break;
      }    
      echo $item->link . '<br />';
      echo $item->title . '<br />';
      echo $item->description . '<br />';
      echo $item->pubDate . '<br />';
      echo '<br />------------------<br /><br />';
      $count++;
  }
  ```
- Crawling: Irá seguir os links e é usado em conjunto com um parser (que irá extrair as informações das páginas). Biblioteca PHP para este fim: [PHPCrawl](http://phpcrawl.cuab.de/)